# Get value from List (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp

I have classes

```
 public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string order_key { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public bool prices_include_tax { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string date_modified { get; set; }
        public int customer_id { get; set; }
        public double discount_total { get; set; }
        public double discount_tax { get; set; }
        public double shipping_total { get; set; }
        public double shipping_tax { get; set; }
        public double cart_tax { get; set; }
        public double total { get; set; }
        public double total_tax { get; set; }
        public Billing billing { get; set; }
        public Shipping shipping { get; set; }
        public string payment_method { get; set; }
        public string payment_method_title { get; set; }
        public string transaction_id { get; set; }
        public string customer_ip_address { get; set; }
        public string customer_user_agent { get; set; }
        public string created_via { get; set; }
        public string customer_note { get; set; }
        public string date_completed { get; set; }
        public string date_paid { get; set; }
        public string cart_hash { get; set; }
        public List<object> line_items { get; set; }
        public List<object> tax_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> shipping_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> fee_lines { get; set; }
        public List<object> coupon_lines { get; set; }

    }
```

I get data like this

```
List<RootObject> rootObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(products);
   foreach (RootObject root in rootObjectData)
        {
            int id = root.id;
            int customer_id = root.customer_id;

            string fio = root.billing.first_name + " " + "  " + root.billing.last_name;
            string adress = root.billing.address_1 + " " + "  " + root.billing.address_2;
            double total = root.total;
            string telephone = root.billing.phone;
```

`line_items` have `List<object>` type

In `line_items`   I have some json with data.

for example

```
"line_items": [
{
  "product_id": 93,
  "quantity": 2
},
{
  "product_id": 22,
  "variation_id": 23,
  "quantity": 1
}
```

],

How I can get for example `product_id`?

Thank's for help so much!

Comment: do you have a search criteria? if so, you could use a linq expression to search a list then extract the value using `Object.Value`

Comment: Yes, I know what fields I need to have.


How I can Search and extract?
@Takarii

Comment: have a quick look at [this page on JSON queries with linq](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) to see if it does what you need

Comment: Look. I have JSON, have classes and have deserealization.

I need to go to list and extract data that I need from it.

like smth that I do with `id`

I edited post@Takarii

Comment: so, using the link i posted, construct the query with linq to get the object containing the value, then directly access that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the very powerful dynamic:

```
List<dynamic> lineItems = jsonObject.line_items;

foreach (dynamic line_item in lineItems)
{
  int productId = line_item.product_id; 
}
```

Keep in mind tho:

It can crash because of renaming/other factors -
`dynamic` is very powerful, but to be used this with caution.

You can also access it directly without need for your "class" that you created - simply deserialize to dynamic and access the fields!

Answer (score 1):

In case if it is not obvious enough

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

foreach(object line_item in line_items)
{
    JObject line_item_jobject = line_item as JObject;
    Jvalue product_id = line_item_jobject["product_id"] as JValue;
    int product_id_value = (int)product_id.Value;

    // Another way
    int product_id_value2 = line_item_jobject.Value<int>("product_id");
}
```